# EventStore C# Client in Azure WebJobs

Tags: .net, azure, azure-webjobs, eventstoredb

I am using WebJob template for Net 4.6.1 and EventStore.Client 4.1.1

In Program.cs

```
var host = new jobHost(config);
host.Call(typeof(Functions).GetMethod("Processmethod"));
host.RunAndBlock;
```

And I have created a public function in a  Functions class such as

```
[NoAutomaticTrigger]
static void ProcessMethod {
```

I am using a persistent connection and this works as a normal console application fine. When I try to have it long running as a WebJob the EvernStore.Client will connect, maybe get 1 event sometimes, then disconnect.

> Close Reason: [Success] Connection close requested by client.

The code is in a using such as

```
using (var conn = EvenStoreConnection.Create....)))
{
  con.ConnectAsync().Wait();

  con.ConnectToPersistentSubscription(STREAM, GROUP, (_,X) =>
  {
    int en = x.EventNumber;
    ...
```

I use a while(true) to block the thread. This works as a normal console app.

Is there something I need to do specifically for WebJobs to keep the connection from dropping out? If I run it locally or in the cloud the same thing happens.

I am just trying to find a way to subscribe to event store events using some Azure way of doing it so we can monitor it. Am I doing this incorrectly maybe? How can I get a persistent Subscription working in Azure?

Comment: autoAck: The client API will automatically acknowledge after the EventAppeared method returns.  If an exception is thrown in the EventAppeared method, the subscription will drop your subscription.Refer to this [article](https://codeopinion.com/event-store-persistent-subscriptions-demo/).

Comment: Thanks. That sample is helpful but the problem turned out to be the while loop was in the wrong place, the connection closed but the WebJob was still running. I will update my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like the client will disconnect depending on various internal events, such as exceptions or errors.

So one of the key options is to use **KeepReconnecting()**

```
 var settings = ConnectionSettings
           .Create()
           .KeepReconnecting()
           .KeepRetrying()
           //.EnableVerboseLogging()
           .UseConsoleLogger();
```

That on its own will prevent the client from dropping out and should reconnect. So the actual connection code will look something like this

```
  _subscription = _conn.ConnectToPersistentSubscription(STREAM, GROUP,
      (_base, _event) => { EventAppeared(_base, _event); },
      (_base, _reason, _exception) => { SubscriptionDropped(_base, _reason, _exception); },
      User, bufferSize, autoAck);
```

That is a bit out of the ordinary for a .NET type of client connection that I have ever worked with. What is happening there is quite obvious for STREAM and GROUP **but the next two are Action<> Delegates** that handle the Event that appeared and the usefull Connection dropped.

In that case for good measure my method for handling the connection closed looks like this

```
private void SubscriptionDropped(EventStorePersistentSubscriptionBase eventStorePersistentSubscriptionBase, SubscriptionDropReason subscriptionDropReason, Exception ex)
{
   Console.WriteLine($"**** Connection dropped reason? '{subscriptionDropReason}' exception? '{ex.Message}'- Reconnecting ...");
   ConnectToSubscription();
}
```

And for the event appeared

```
private static void EventAppeared(EventStorePersistentSubscriptionBase eventStorePersistentSubscriptionBase, ResolvedEvent resolvedEvent)
{
    var x = resolvedEvent;
    ... your code
}
```

This persistent subscriber has been running for weeks without issue, as an AppService WebJob!

- [I have written a blog post about this](http://pkula.blogspot.com/2018/06/eventstore-persistent-subscriptions.html)
- [I have WORKING sample code up in Github](https://github.com/ppumkin/EventStoreAzureWebJobPersistentSubscriber)